# How to handle the schema or stored procedure change logs in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL :-

How to handle the schema or stored procedure change logs in a table?

Whenever there some changes applied on the stored procedure, that change has to be store in a table. Changes will provide additional details on what was changed and when was changed. Will it be possible to store the change logs in a table? 
If so, how we do that?

Comment: A simpler and more robust approach would be to use version control on your database.

Comment: That is maintaining every scripts through source safe repository ? Check-In / Check-Out from Visual Studio Environment ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DDL Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) for this. See the list of [DDL Events here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events?view=sql-server-2017)

[Aaron Bertrand has blogged about this, and has provided some useful scripts.](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/)

Comment: What about stored procedure changes .. and do we have a script to insert those changes

Comment: Sure thing, see the blog i attached