# SQL : Managing change log in a Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

SQL : Managing change log in a Table

On every Create , Alter SP / UDF / Trigger / View scripts, I will have to add an entry in a table along with the entire script syntax. Table will have a row of record which has user who changed, date time , database the change taken, whole script.

In SQL, How to do that in an effective way ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle the schema or stored procedure change logs in a table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53176026/how-to-handle-the-schema-or-stored-procedure-change-logs-in-a-table)

Comment: any reason why either time i answered the question it wasn't good enough? No comments / follow on questions? They have both gone stale.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [DDL Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-2017) for these kind of changes. [See the DDL Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-events?view=sql-server-2017) which include all of the events you want to capture.

If you want the easy button, SQL Server [MVP Aaron Bertrand wrote something a good while back](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/) to track these kind of changes.

Answer (score 0):

As it is mostly the table structure updation and then inserting data so best choice go for ddl trigger on creation of table then alter the table as the after action when action is triggered

Comment: I created a custom  table and planning to insert the scripts in a column. To give an example : sp_helptext 'sp_testprocdure' will return the script. How do i save the whole script in a column.